# Prevent Repeating Code in android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Is There anyway to prevent repeating code in android layout xml?
for example I have layout that has a TabLayout I want to show Tablayout in in
Right to Left Direction so I use  android:layoutDirection="rtl"
But as you know this is not supported under API 17 so I have to override my Code for API 17. But each time I want to modify my layout I have to repeat  same actions in both xml file is there any easy and better way?

Layout for  API 17:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/main_background_color">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/promotion_type_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFF"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"


        />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/promotion_view_pager"
    android:background="@color/main_background_color" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and Layout for Under API 17:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/main_background_color">


   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/promotion_type_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFF"


        />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/promotion_view_pager"
    android:background="@color/main_background_color" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could export the layouts in their own file and `<include/>` them in the `Activity/Fragment` layout e.g.

```
 <include layout="@layout/base_table" />
```

See the developer guide [Re-using Layouts with include](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this way but I think this is overwhelming
because we face with lots of layout files in resource

Comment: @MahdiYusefi Even more reason to re-use layouts.

Comment: I don't sure. if there is no better way this would be a serious flaw in designing android layout.
Anyway, thanks for your answer and attention.